# What is the aws-cli command for AWS Macie to create a job?

Tags: amazon-web-services

actually I want to create a job in AWS macie using the aws cli.
I ran the following command:-
***aws macie2 create-classification-job --job-type "ONE_TIME" --name "maice-poc" --s3-job-definition bucketDefinitions=[{"accountID"="254378651398", "buckets"=["maice-poc"]}]***

but it is giving me an error:-
***Unknown options: buckets=[maice-poc]}]***

Can someone give me a correct command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [s3-job-definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/macie2/create-classification-job.html) requires a structure as value.

And in your case, you want to pass in a JSON-formatted structure parameter, so you [should wrap the JSON starting with `bucketDefinitions` in single quotes.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-shorthand.html#shorthand-structure-parameters) Also instead of `=` use the JSON syntax `:` for key-value pairs.

The following API call should work:

```
aws macie2 create-classification-job --job-type "ONE_TIME" --name "macie-poc" --s3-job-definition '{"bucketDefinitions":[{"accountId":"254378651398", "buckets":["maice-poc"]}]}'
```